# Spark SQL : custom Hive UDF GenericInternalRow cannot be cast ArrayData

Tags: apache-spark, hive, user-defined-functions

I'm using **Spark 1.6** with Scala and R (throught SparkR and SparkLyr)

I have a dataframe containing binary data representing a Double 2D array. I want to deserialize binary data with an Hive UDF (for compatibility with R), but Spark crash with the error :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericInternalRow cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.ArrayData
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BaseGenericInternalRow$class.getArray(rows.scala:48)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericInternalRow.getArray(rows.scala:221)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$ArrayConverter.toScalaImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:190)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$ArrayConverter.toScalaImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:153)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toScala(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:110)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toScala(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:283)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toScala(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:250)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToScalaConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:414)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeCollectPublic$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:174)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeCollectPublic$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:174)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>           at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectPublic(SparkPlan.scala:174)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:2086)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1(DataFrame.scala:1498)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect(DataFrame.scala:1505)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1375)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1374)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withCallback(DataFrame.scala:2099)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1374)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.take(DataFrame.scala:1456)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.showString(DataFrame.scala:170)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:350)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:311)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:319)

Here is the **UDF** class :

```
class DeserBytesTo2DArrayDouble extends UDF {
def evaluate(input: BytesWritable): Array[Array[Double]] = { 
    if (input == null) return null
    val res = SerializationUtils.deserializeFromByteArray(input.getBytes, 
    classOf[Array[Array[Double]]])
    logger.info("Deserialized data : {}",res)
    res
}
 }
```

And an example for using it :

```
val data = Array(Array(1d,2d,3d))
val bytArr = SerializationUtils.serializeToByteArray(data)
val df = List(("a", bytArr)).toDF("ID", "DATAB")
df.registerTempTable("toto")
sqlContext.sql("CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION b2_2darrD as 'package.to.DeserBytesTo2DArrayDouble'")
sqlContext.sql("select id, b2_2darrD(datab) from toto").show
```